# Request to http://localhost:8545 from https website

Tags: web3js, testrpc, ganache

I am building a website that should interact (from the browser, not back-end) with custom Ethereum nodes, including local, something like MyEtherWallet.
I can connect to ganache **http**://localhost:8545 with no problems if the website itself is served via **http**.

If I switch website to **https**, then I get an error when trying to web3.eth.call for example

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:8545/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Which seems strange for it reports **https**://localhost:8545/, not **http**.
I guess it relates to problems with https-to-http requests. But I am pretty sure there is a way to overcome this error as MyEtherWallet has no difficulties with connecting to my local **http** ganache.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like an HTTP issue, not an Ethereum issue. You're much more likely to get answer to that on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Ganache was created to work in the dev context and not on actual production purposes.

The `https` support requires to deal with certificate issues, that the developer team doesn't plan to deal with. So you won't be getting that directly anyway.

But, in your project `webpack-dev-server` you can add a proxy for `https`.
Or, use ngnix to setup a reverse proxy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand that, however, MyEtherWallet has no issues with it